# Proximity and WiFiDirect hardware requirements

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

How can I know in advance (Without testing it. Just by reading its specs) that a phone supports [Proximity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.proximity.aspx)   and [WiFiDirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.wifidirect.aspx)   ? Do they have some special hardware requirements? Are they dependent only on wifi being available?

Comment: `WiFiDirect` is definitely dependent on WiFi. However, `Proximity` is a hardware sensor and isn't dependent on WiFi. Both `WiFiDirect` and `Proximity` are mentioned as feature on [GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/) e.g. [Nexus 5x](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_nexus_5x-7556.php)

Comment: @M.Hassan The proximity mentioned there is (as far as I know) a different type - it's an IR sensor to prevent a user's ear from pressing buttons on a phone. The one I'm referring to is for communication.

Answer (score 0):

The following android device will have the Wifi-Direct :

1. Wi-Fi Direct support in Android 4.0 or later
2. Phone should be android
3. Wi-Fi Direct became available with the Blackberry 10.2 upgrade
4. Iphone doesn't support this.